# Skill bot sending proactive messages to a user

Tags: botframework

1. I have developed a bot which sends Proactive messages to user
2. I also cretaed bots which trigger skills.
   I was trying to write something where a skills bot/Dialog would be able to send proactive message received via webhooks to the user and continue with the existing Skill dialog.
   I am not able to quite understand that. If anyone could help me there.

I used the sample from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/80.skills-simple-bot-to-bot) to create a simple Skill bot which saves the `ConversationReference` of the current Activity and calls a service in `OnMessageActivityReceived()`

```cs
// Save ConversationReference
var conversationReference = activity.GetConversationReference();
_conversationReferences.AddOrUpdate(conversationReference.User.Id, conversationReference, (key, newValue) => conversationReference);

// Calling external service
HttpResponseMessage responsemMsg = await client.PostAsync(RequestURI, stringContent);
if (responsemMsg.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var apiResponse = await responsemMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    //Post the API response to bot again
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Message Sent {turnContext.Activity.Text}"), cancellationToken);

}
```

The called service eventually emits an event which calls an action in the `NotifyController` in my Skills Bot. It tries to grab the `ConverstaionReference` and send the activity using the `TurnContext`.

```
//I am using the Skill Bot Id for _appId parameter
await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, async (context, token) =>
 {
     await context.SendActivityAsync(proMsg.eventName);
     await context.SendActivityAsync(proMsg.context.ToString());
  }, new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
```

This SendActivity fails and OnTurnError from the Skill Bot handles the exception.
I am not sure where excatly I am going wrong. I am new to the Bot framework learning.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you can provide some code you are working on and what errors or roadblocks you are facing, people will be better able to help you.

Comment: @billoverton I have updated my question to add code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I created the `ClaimsIdentity`:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<Claim> lclaim = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(AuthenticationConstants.VersionClaim, "2.0"),
            new Claim(AuthenticationConstants.AudienceClaim, <SkillBotId>),
            new Claim(AuthenticationConstants.AppIdClaim, <SkillBotId>),
            new Claim(AuthenticationConstants.AuthorizedParty, <SkillBotId>),
        };
        ClaimsIdentity ci = new ClaimsIdentity(lclaim);

        async Task BotCallBack(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken token)
        {
            <code to send activity back to parent bot>
        }

        await ((BotAdapter)this.botFrameworkHttpAdapter).ContinueConversationAsync(
            ci,
            conversationData.ConversationReference,
            <ParentBotId>,
            callback: BotCallBack,
            default).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: @ksk please see the sample here

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved by using the ContinueConversation() overload with ClaimsIdentity and setting the right claims for audience, appid etc. It was basically authentication issue.

```
public virtual Task ContinueConversationAsync(ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity, ConversationReference reference, string audience, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm facing similar issue (cannot create proactive conversation from skill because unauthorized exception) can you please share how did you manage to create valid claimsIdentity and audience parameters?

Comment: can you share the code? I tried to create claim and use it from request but it is failing with Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter: Error: Exception caught in SendErrorMessageAsync : System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'clientSecret')
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential..ctor(String clientId, String clientSecret)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.MicrosoftAppCredentials.<BuildAuthenticator>b__14_0()

Comment: I'm facing same issue, can you help me with sample please

Comment: @KSK - The sample is shared in the below answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69080456/1647012), please check